# Python - Webscraping a webpage

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to web scrape a page using BeautifulSoup. The page contains list of products (name, list price). I am using the following code to start

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("https://www.example.com")
c = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(c, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

but rather than HTML this returns some sort of scripts. But when accessing and inspecting the web page in the browser (Chrome), I can see the HTML code without any problems.

This is the part of the returned code of the script above

```
data.listing = [
{
  "empty": false,
  "baseProduct": {
    "data": {
      "code": "123",
      "variants": ["567"],
      "brandData": {
        "code": "20",
        "name": "brand",
        "urlCode": "brand"
      },
      "productPictureForVariantSelectionEnabled": false,
      "validVariantGroups": false
    }
  }
}
]
```

1) Why does the soup does not return the HTML code I see in the browser?

2) How to parse such list of dictionaries data?

Comment: 1) Why does the soup does not return the HTML code I see in the browser? The page may be dynamic. Can you share the url?

2) How to parse such list of dictionaries data? you could use `json` package. either `json.loads()`, or if it thats return from `requests()`, use `requests.get().json()`

Comment: Thanks. This is the URL: https://www.moebelix.cz/zahradni-nabytek-C16

Comment: @happyno you've to [edit] your question and include your desired output.